# If condition must be associated with curly braces?

Tags: ballerina

In ballerina if condition related statements should associated with the curly braces. This is required even if there is a single statement associated with the if condition. Is it normal or is it a convention associated with the ballerina language ?

```
var a = 10;
if (a > 10) io:println("Value is high"); // This shows an error with the IDE

if(a > 10){
   io:println("Value is high"); // This is the correct format recognized as 
   the correct way
}
```

In first method it says as mismatch of input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the curly braces are mandatory. Refer https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/if-else.html

Comment: Thank you for helping. I will refer the resource.